# Заменяющие значение при объединение MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, запрос

Добрый день. Есть две таблицы `sm_imei` и `sm_city`.

**Структура sm_imei**

- imei_id
- imei1
- imei2
- sn
- name
- phone
- brand
- model
- region
- city
- date_added

**Структура sm_city**

- city_id
- region_id
- name

Нужно сделать объединение с замещением значения в результате запроса.
Например запрос.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sm_imei im 
  LEFT JOIN sm_city ci ON 
    im.city=ci.city_id 
WHERE
  imei1='99999' OR 
  imei2='99999'
ORDER BY
  `imei_id` ASC
```

Вернет все значения как и ему и положено.

А нужно что бы вместо `sm_imei.city` значения в этом столбце появилось значение `sm_city.name`[image: Пример того что нужно]

Comment: Помогите решить данную задачу или дайте пожалуйста ссылку на материал по подобной теме в сети.

Comment: Вам нужно `SELECT * FROM` переписать на выборку нужных столбцов в нужном вам порядке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT im.imei_id, im.imei2, im.sn, im.phone, im.brand, im.model, im.region, ci.name AS city, im.date_added from sm_imei as im LEFT JOIN sm_city AS ci ON im.region = ci.region_id ABD im.city = ci.city_id WHERE imei1 = '99999' OR imei2 = '99999' ORDER BY im.imei_id
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все заработало. А есть примеры в сети? Что бы подробнее изучить.